# LinqToTwitter C# library erroring out when calling CreateFriendshipAsync

Tags: c#, twitter, linq-to-twitter

I have been using LinqToTwitter's CreateFriendshipAsync method since quite a while, but all of a sudden it started to give the following error:

> Invalid character '<' in input string

After doing authorization from Twitter when it returns to callback URL, using the returned AccessToken and AccessSecret to initialize the LinqToTwitter's TwitterContext method and twitter client. After that calling the CreateFriendshipAsync passing the twitter username to follow.

It was working fine but today it gave strange error.
Does anyone can tell me what could possibly go wrong.
I am using LinqToTwitter version 3.05, I have tried with latest version 3.1.2, but getting same error.

Comment: You may have an invalid cookie.  Try removing cookies from IE history and try again.  A cookie may of changed but you still have an old cookie that hasn't expired.

Comment: A few thing would be helpful to debug: (1) code example, (2) show input values that cause the problem, and (3) full exception details.